# Javascript associative array(Dictionary) not working

Tags: javascript

It's strange that my below JS code alert empty.

```
    // Used as Dictionary:
    var dict = new Array();
    dict['STAR'] = "star";
    dict['MOUTH'] = "mouth";
    dict['HAND'] = "hand";
    alert(dict);
    alert(dict("MOUTH"));
```

Any advice?

---

P.S. Thanks all! I know where is wrong!alert(dict("MOUTH"));  -- should be alert(dict["MOUTH"]);

Comment: My advice, learn JavaScript.

Comment: dict is not a function; use dict['MOUTH']

Comment: The problem is not the `dict[...]`. Using Array as a hash is pretty horrible, which looks like what you keep doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a thing as associative array in JS.

You can do the same with an object:

```
var dict = {};
dict['STAR'] = "star";
dict['MOUTH'] = "mouth";
dict['HAND'] = "hand";
alert(dict);
alert(dict["MOUTH"]);
```

Or, if the keys are valid variable names, you can write them as properties:

```
dict.star = "star";
dict.mouth = ...;
```

Or use direct literal:

```
var dict = {
    star: "star",
    mouth: "mouth",
    hand: "hand"
};
```

In fact, in JS there is no 100% equivalent to a Dictionary/associative array, since even empty objects have their own methods (for instance `hasOwnProperty`), which means that you can overwrite "native" elements of the objects. There are workarounds to this, though, like using `Object.create(null)` which is a completely empty object, but not available in all browsers... or using getters and setters with prefixes.

Comment: `alert(dict["MOUTH"]);`.

Comment: Have you downvoted me for that?... both " and ' are string delimiters in JS.

Comment: dict is not a function!

Comment: Nope, I didn't downvote. But that's not what's wrong. It's the parens `()` instead of brackets `[]`.

Comment: @ikaros45: thanks a lot! I accepted it as the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Used as Dictionary:
var dict = {};
dict['STAR'] = "star";
dict['MOUTH'] = "mouth";
dict['HAND'] = "hand";
alert(dict);
alert(dict["MOUTH"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like that:

```
var dict = {
    STAR: "star",
    MOUTH: "mouth",
    HAND: "hand"
};

alert(dict);
alert(dict.MOUTH);
```

Comment: Would you like to add some explanation?